# reducing the header/footer size in bootstrap navbar css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am newbie to bootstrap css. Facing probelm in adjusting height of header and footer.

code for footer:

```
<div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">What is thenWat?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">How does it work?</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Feedback</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>                            
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is codepen with added css:

[Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/hxatC)

similarly link to header: [link to header demo](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/fpmdw)

Can someone tell me how to reduce the height or footer?

I tried with reducing height in header footer class but no change.

What is the logic behind editing bootstrap elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the height of the header in the Customize section on Bootstrap official site:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#variables-navbar

Looking for the variable `@navbar-height`.

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sHLmJ

Comment: @amaterllanes: `.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
` but no change

Comment: You have to compile your own version of Bootstrap specifying your @navbar-height value. It works.

Comment: `@` need to be included?

Comment: 1. Visit this page: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ 2.In this page, looking for the input to @navbar-height.  3. Write here your custom navbar height (for instance, 30px). 4 At the bottom of the page, click in the button 'Compile and Download'. 5 Replace your current bootstrap.css file for the new one you just downloaded.

Comment: I already made few changes in local css. no success yet. I appreciate if you can give ansew for this: http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/hxatC